# When hiring freelancers, do I give them contracts?

Tags: contracts, startups

As a startup that isn't a company yet and still starting out. Do I need contracts to sign up freelancers? This is for digital projects and haven't seen need to start a company yet without revenues.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly *can*.... and the Freelancer may have a contract already.

Contracts are designed to clearly identify what is to be done by each party so there are no misunderstandings. It is *never* a bad idea to write responsibilities down so everyone has the same expectations.

Answer (score 2):

When you hire someone for a task, this establishes a contract. Even just orally. All that matters for both parties is that there is evidence of a mutual agreement.

But it is much better for both parties to have a formal contract, which mostly specifies in advance the scope of the work, and what to do if things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think a contract is very necessary for any company or freelancer because it guarantees the benefits of both parties. Besides, it also shows the clarity of money when working, minimizing the dispute.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need contracts to sign up freelancers?

1,000 times yes. You should have contracts with anyone and everyone that you engage with in a business relationship.